# maximum of independent random variable convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $(X_n)$ are independent such that $P(X_n>x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\ge 2$. I am trying to show that $\max_{1\le i\le n}X_n\to \infty$.

We know that $\prod(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$ converges since $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. To to that end $$ P(\max_{1\le i\le n} X_i > n)=1-\prod_{i=2}^n(1-\frac{1}{n^2}) $$

but I am unsure how to go from this.

Comment: Where does $1/n^2$ come from?  It seems to be different from your $1/x$ distribution information.

Comment: Have a look at the Borel Cantelli Theorem. Try to use this to show that $P(X_n > n \mbox{ infinitly often})=1$

Comment: @Michael, just choose $x=n$. its a common technique

Comment: Choosing $x=n$ gives $P[X_n>n] = 1/n$.  So I do not know why you are consistently writing $1/n^2$. There also seem to be a number of indexing errors in your work.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i$ is increasing its limit $Y$ exits (but it may be $\infty$). Now $P( \max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i\leq t)=P(X_1 \leq t)^{n}=(1-\frac 1 t )^{n} \to 0$ for every $t \geq 2$ and $P( \max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i\leq t)=0$ if $t <2$. This proves that $P(Y \leq t)=0$ for all $ t \in \mathbb R$ and  this is same thing as saying that $Y=\infty$ with probability $1$.